# Why const keyword without identifier in function parameter compiles?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw

As I was playing with the C++ syntax, I coded something I thought wouldn't compile.

The following code is simplified to isolate the problem:

```
void foo(const) {} //why doesn't the compiler flag this line as error?
int main() {}
```

I compiled the above source code for C++ on MinGW's g++ compiler, and it did so without any warning or error.

Out of curiosity, I would like to know if there is any intention behind why const is allowed without a following identifier inside a function parameter.

Or is this perhaps a bug?

**EDIT:** Take a look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6XNA.gif) and witness the mystery yourself.

Comment: I get "error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no type [-fpermissive]" when I do this on Ideone.com. Perhaps you have set that flag somewhere.

Comment: Just tried it on Ubuntu 17.04 with G++, same error as InternetAussie reported, it's not allowed.

Comment: What versions of g++ are both of you using? Have you added any additional compiler commands?

Comment: @Christian I just turned off my laptop, I'm on PC right now, I use default version of g++ that comes with Ubuntu 17.04, try to google it. No additional parameters to the compiler, just a default compile: 

g++ programname.cpp

Comment: @FairPlay I just tested it online and it did gave an error. Well that's strange, I'm using g++ 6.3.0 (next to its current release), yet it compiles. Guess my curiosity ends here.

Comment: GCC 6.3 also refuses it: https://godbolt.org/g/ANAZhD  - I guess you did something else wrong.

Comment: @JohnZwinck That's really strange. Have a look at the gif I have attached in the post.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running your compiler without enabling useful warnings.  Many compilers emit only the diagnostics that the Standard requires them to, unless you specifically ask for more:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -fPIC -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Weffc++     -c -o 16019202.o 16019202.cpp
16019202.cpp:1:10: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘parameter’ with no type [-fpermissive]
 void foo(const) {} //why doesn't the compiler flag this line as error?
          ^~~~~
```

(That's with GCC 6.3.0 on Debian).

Comment: But without adding additional parameters to the compiler, does the compiler on your machine skip the error on line 1 too?

Comment: @Christian - I disabled non-default warnings, and it seems that GCC 6.3 does report the error by default.  But it's not required to, so it's perfectly allowed to keep quiet (and I guess your compiler is a quiet one).